# PHP Mail Form Sending Random Emails Daily

Tags: php, html

I'm using a basic PHP mail form on a website & my client has mentioned to me that he is getting a random email every day or so in his inbox that is totally blank. I read about the issue and was thinking that the mail form is sending an email every time the page is loaded, is that correct? Or is this another issue?

**PHP**

```
<?php     

$mail_to = "email1@gmail.com, email2@gmail.com"; // specify your email here


// Assigning data from the $_POST array to variables

$name = $_POST['sender_name'];

$mail_from = $_POST['sender_email'];

$phone = $_POST['sender_phone'];

$web = $_POST['sender_web'];

$company = $_POST['sender_company'];

$addy = $_POST['sender_addy'];

$message = $_POST['sender_message'];


// Construct email subject

$subject = 'Web Prayer Request from ' . $name;


// Construct email body

$body_message = 'From: ' . $name . "\r\n";

$body_message .= 'E-mail: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n";

$body_message .= 'Phone: ' . $phone . "\r\n";

$body_message .= 'Prayer Request: ' . $message;



// Construct email headers

$headers = 'From: ' . $name . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $mail_from . "\r\n";

$mail_sent = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);


if ($mail_sent == true){ ?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
alert('Your prayer request has been submitted - thank you.');

window.location = 'prayer-request.php';

</script>

<?php } else { ?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
alert('Message not sent. Please, notify the site administrator info@info.com');

window.location = 'prayer-request.php';
</script>

<?php

    }

?>
```

**Link to site: http://tinyurl.com/dy48jom**

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: You aren't checking if variables have content in them. EG checking if email is valid email, url is valid, etc. Also you might want to add tokens.

Comment: please include captcha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to consider implementing captcha in your mail form so that automated scripts wont send mail from your domain .[captcha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) also make sure that you make some of the fields as `required` (validate not only using js but also using server side php code).